# Creating form with jquery/AJax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple Contact Us form placed in Div..
What i want is when user submits the form, After proper validation, instead of redirecting to other thank you page, I just want to remove the contact form from that Div and show him the "Thank You" Message

How do i do that ? Demo/Download Code will be helpful

Comment: Please try out some tutorials first and if you get stuck anywhere, we are here to help you. A simple 'jquery ajax contact form' search in google will get you plenty of tutorials

Answer (score 0):

A bit of searching would be great ;)

```
<div id="form>
[ Your HTML Form]
</div>
<script>
$([form]).submit(function () {
   $("#id").html("Thank You");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, great and widely used jQuery Form plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

You can use this plugin to submit the form using ajax and then on success callback, show the appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#submitBtn").click(function () {
$("#divId").html("Loading PleaseWait"); //divId contain all the text field
    $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                data: "data=" + $("#data").val(),   //id of the text field (value)
                url: "demo.php",                    //page name to which u r passing the value
                success: function(msg){
                if($("#divId").html(msg))
                { 
                    $("#divId").html("Thank You");
                }

            }); 
});
```